# Is there a DllMap equivalent for MSBuild

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, sfml, visual-studio-mac

So I'm trying to write a C# app on Mac OS Mojave using Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition. I'm using a library called SFML.Net. There's a C binding called CSFML. It seems that SFML.Net uses the CSFML dynamic libraries (i.e. `libcsfml-graphics.2.5.0.dylib`) to do the low level work.

I created a C# project and added the SFML.Net NuGet. At this point, the project *builds* just fine with no errors. However, if I *run* the project, I get a `System.DllNotFoundException` with the message being just `csfml-graphics`.

Now here is what the [SFML.Net download page](https://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml.net/) has to say:

> Since it's a .Net library, there's only one archive per architecture,
>   which works for any OS and compiler. However, since the name of CSFML
>   libraries appear in the source code, and are different on each OS, for
>   OS X and Linux you will have to write a special configuration file
>   which maps the names of the CSFML DLLs to the names of the
>   corresponding CSFML shared libraries on your OS (for example,
>   "csfml-graphics-2.dll" -> "libcsfml-graphics.so.2"); see [the Mono documentation](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/dllmap/) for more details.

So I copied the `.dylib` file to the bin/Debug folder of my project. Now according to that Mono documentation link, I can do a simple DLL mapping in Mono:

```
<configuration>
  <dllmap dll="csfml-graphics.dll" target="libcsfml-graphics.2.5.0.dylib"/>
</configuration>
```

Unfortunately, according to [this Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/customizing-build-system?view=vsmac-2019), it seems that Mono is no longer used by Visual Studio for Mac:

> MSBuild is a build engine, developed by Microsoft, that allows for the
>   building of primarily .NET applications. The Mono framework also has
>   its own implementation of Microsoft's Build Engine, called xbuild.
>   However, xbuild has been phased out in favor of using MSBuild on all
>   operating systems.
>
> MSBuild is primarily used for as the build system for projects in
>   Visual Studio for Mac.

Is there any analogue to Mono's `dllmap` in MSBuild? I need to tell the .Net runtime that instead of looking for `csfml-graphics.dll`, it should be looking for `libcsfml-graphics.2.5.0.dylib`.

**UPDATE:**

In the Mono global config file I added

```
<dllmap dll="csfml-graphics" target="libcsfml-graphics.2.5.0.dylib" />
```

This changed the `DllNotFoundException` message to `libcsfml-graphics.2.5.0.dylib`. So the mapping worked I guess, but now I'm not sure why Mono can't find the DLL; it's sitting in the `bin/Debug` folder for my project.

I tried putting the `.dylib` in a folder called `~/CSFML` and changed the config line to

```
<dllmap dll="csfml-graphics" target="~/CSFML/libcsfml-graphics.2.5.0.dylib" />
```

I thought maybe an absolute path would work. Unfortunate this still gives a `DllNotFoundException`, except now this time the message says `~/CSFML/libcsfml-graphics.2.5.0.dylib`...

**UPDATE 2:**

I tried to follow [this tutorial](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/wiki/Tutorial:-SFML.Net-on-OSX) on how to set up SFML.Net on Mac. I did the step where I use InstallNameToolGUI to change the ID of `.dylib`. I changed in from `@rpath/libcsfml-graphics.2.5.0.dylib` to just `libcsfml-graphics.2.5.0.dylib`.

I should note that I reverted the DLL mapping in the Mono config file back to

```
<dllmap dll="csfml-graphics" target="libcsfml-graphics.2.5.0.dylib" />
```

I *still* get the `DllNotFoundException` with message to `libcsfml-graphics.2.5.0.dylib`

Comment: VS Mac runs on top of Mono. Mono is a runtime. MSBuild is used to compile the project. If you are writing a C# console project then Mono will be used to run it. So the dllmap should still be used. According to the [Mono doc](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/#library-names) the dllmap is put in the app.config for the project. Which msbuild will convert into either assemblyname.exe.config or assemblyname.dll.config depending on the project type.

Comment: @MattWard I took your suggestions and made an update to my post